# If one table doesn't have value get it from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, sql-server-2012

I have two properties table.

```
Table1: App_conf
prop_name
prop_value
prop_desc

Table2: Client_conf
client_id
prop_name
prop_value
prop_desc
```

I want to write a query where first I need to check in `Client_conf` table with a particular `prop_name` and `client_id`. If there is no matching rows in `Client_conf` table, then I need to check `App_conf` table with the `prop_name`.

E.g., values in App_conf table:

```
'Max Amount Limit', '2000', 'Maximum amount'
'Min Amount Limit', '200', 'Minimum amount'
```

Values in Client_conf table:

```
'1','Max Amount Limit', '1500', 'Maximum amount'
```

**Case 1:**

```
prop_name = 'Max Amount Limit', client_id = '1'
```

In this case, I need the value 1500 from Client_conf table.

**Case 2:**

```
prop_name = 'Min Amount Limit', client_id = '1'
```

Since this is not present in Client_conf table, I need to get the value from App_conf table and the result will be 200.

I need to do this in a single query with optimum performance.

I am using MS SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could left join the `client_conf` table on the `app_conf` table so you get `null`s where there **isn't** an appropriate client configuration. The use `coalesce` to ensure you get some configuration, where the client's conf. is prioritized in case it exists:

```
SELECT    a.prop_name,
          a.prop_desc
          COALESCE(c.prop_value, a.prop_value) AS prop_value,
FROM      app_conf a
LEFT JOIN client_conf c ON a.prop_name = c.prop_name AND 
          c.client_id = 'some id'
WHERE     a.prop_name = 'some name' AND
```

Comment: This will only return a prop_value when the record exists in client_conf as you are doing a LEFT JOIN, but then expecting a value for client_id in your WHERE clause.

Comment: Nice catch @William, thanks. Moved the `client_id` condition to the `join` clause where it belongs.

Comment: If 'some name' is not present in app_conf table, this query will not return value. In such a condition, i need to get the value from client_conf table. Can you please help?

Comment: @DivyaRose you could use a `full outer join` instead of a `left join`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT    COALESCE(CC.prop_value, AC.prop_value) AS prop_value,
FROM      app_conf AS AC LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                client_conf AS CC ON AC.prop_name = CC.prop_name
WHERE     AC.prop_name = 'Min Amount Limit' AND
          (CC.client_id = '1' OR CC.client_id IS NULL)
```

Presuming that prop_name is a valid link between the tables, and is unique.